# Assign number by appearance and then cumsum by iD

Tags: python, pandas

This is an example of my data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C'], 'val': [1,2,-3,1,5,6,-2], 'date':['01-01-2020','01-02-2020','01-03-2020','01-04-2020','01-02-2020','01-03-2020','01-06-2020']})

print(df)
  id  val        date
0  A    1  01-01-2020
1  B    2  01-02-2020
2  A   -3  01-03-2020
3  C    1  01-04-2020
4  D    5  01-02-2020
5  B    6  01-03-2020
6  C   -2  01-06-2020
```

I'm new at pandas and python and what I need it's to count the rows of apperance by id, sort it by date and then do the cumsum of the appearances of the id, something like this  :

```
print(df)
  id  val        date cumsum 
0  A    1  01-01-2020   1
1  A   -3  01-02-2020   2
2  B    2  01-02-2020   1
3  B    6  01-03-2020   2 
4  C    1  01-04-2020   1
5  C   -2  01-06-2020   2
6  D    5  01-02-2020   1
```

I tried using df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(['id','date'])['id'].cumsum() but obviously I cant sum id, and if i use val i get the sum of the values.. What can i do ? thnks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets try `groupby`, `cumsum`()

```
df=df.assign(cumsum=df.groupby('id')['val','date'].cumcount()+1).sort_values(by=['id'])
```

Comment: remember that cumcount starts at zero so that why @wwnde added one

Comment: thank you for your answer @wwnde . I have one more question, if I have more columns, how can i avoid using the cumcount or cumsum on them? i have to add the columns on the [ ] of the groupby? for example ['val','date','col4',...] ? or its not neccesary ?

Comment: @M. Weithofer exclude those columns you dont want to use from the list/[] and you should be fine. If this answer is working for you, do you mind accepting it?